# Program to create list of all English Wikipedia articles

Tags: python, html, windows, web-scraping

This program will scrape Wikipedia to create a list of all English Wikipedia articles.

How can I improve this program as it currently performs very badly performance-wise? On my Internet connection it takes about 1-2 secs per processed link.

```
import wget             # I use wget for downloading the files
import os               # for deleting the cached html file + clearing the screen
import re               # for extracting the urls out of the html file
import timeit           # for timing the runtime of every processed page
import sys


base_url = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/'  # standard url if the queue is empty.
session_urls = 0
runtimes = []
average_runtime = 0

if os.path.isfile('cache/page'):
    os.remove('cache/page')


def serialize_urls(urls):
    """
    convert a list like ['article1','article2','article3']
    into a string like 'article1|article2|article3' for saving it to file
    """
    buffer = ''
    for url in urls:
        buffer += url + '|'
    return buffer


def get_urls(path):
    """
    reads string (format: 'article1|article2|article3') from either 'queue' or
    'database/page_index' and converts it to a list (format: ['article1','article2','article3'])
    """
    index_file = open(path, 'r', encoding='utf8')
    raw_data = index_file.read()
    index_file.close()
    urls = raw_data.split('|')
    if path == 'queue':
        urls = [x for x in urls if x != '']
    return urls


def create_url():
    """
    concatenates the base_url (= 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/') and
    the url (wikipedia article name) to get the full http url
    """
    global queue
    if queue == [''] or not queue:  # fix this, refactor
        queue = ['Main_Page']

    url = base_url + queue[0]
    del queue[0]
    return url


def fetch_page(url):
    """
    downloads the html file at 'url', saves it's contents to the var 'page'
    and deletes the temp html file from 'cache/page'
    """
    wget.download(url, out='cache/page', bar=None)
    page_file = open('cache/page', 'r', encoding='utf8')
    page = page_file.read()
    page_file.close()
    os.remove('cache/page')
    return page


def parse_urls(page):
    """
    searches for all internal wikipedia urls in the html file and returns them
    """
    raw_urls = re.findall(r'href=[\'"]?/wiki/([^\'" >]+)', page)
    return raw_urls


def filter_urls(raw_urls):
    """
    removes all internal wikipedia help urls from the url list

    e.g.:
    Help:Something
    File:image.png
    Discussion:Topic

    all of these contain a ':' so I can just remove urls containing a ':'
    """
    cnt = 0
    while cnt < len(raw_urls):
        if ':' in raw_urls[cnt]:
            del raw_urls[cnt]
        else:
            cnt += 1
    return raw_urls


def remove_existing_urls(url_base, urls):
    """
    removes all urls from the new urls that were extracted from the html if they:
    1. are already in the queue
    2. have already been processed (and therefore are in 'database/page_index')
    """
    cnt = 0
    while cnt < len(urls):
        if urls[cnt] in url_base:
            del urls[cnt]
        else:
            cnt += 1
    return list(set(urls))


def write_to_disk(url, new_urls):
    queue_obj = open('queue', 'a', encoding='utf8')
    queue_obj.write(serialize_urls(new_urls))
    queue_obj.close()
    page_index_obj = open('database/page_index', 'a', encoding='utf8')
    page_index_obj.write(url[29:] + '|')
    page_index_obj.close()




def process_next_url():
    global average_runtime, session_urls, queue, page_index

    start = timeit.default_timer()

    url = create_url()
    page = fetch_page(url)
    raw_urls = parse_urls(page)
    urls = filter_urls(raw_urls)

    page_index.append(url)

    new_urls = remove_existing_urls(queue + page_index, urls)

    queue = queue + new_urls  # refactor queue += new_urls(?)


    stop = timeit.default_timer()
    time = stop - start
    os.system('cls')
    if queue == []: #refactor? # own function for output
        print('Article: Main_Page')
    else:
        print('Article: ' + queue[0])
    print('Page Index: ' + str(len(page_index)))
    print('Queue: ' + str(len(queue)))
    print('Average Runtime: ' + str(average_runtime))
    print('Runtime: ' + str(time))
    print('URLs Processed: ' + str(session_urls))
    print('Full URL: ' + url)
    return time, url, new_urls


def check_cmd():
    file = open('cmd', 'r', encoding='utf8')
    cmd = file.read()
    if cmd == 'stop\n':
        os.system('cls')
        file = open('cmd', 'w', encoding='utf8')
        file.write('')
        sys.exit(0)
    file.close()

queue = get_urls('queue')
page_index = get_urls('database/page_index')

while True:
    for cnt in range(100):
        session_urls += 1
        time, url, new_urls = process_next_url()
        runtimes.append(time)
    write_to_disk(url, new_urls)
    average_runtime = str(sum(runtimes) / len(runtimes))
    runtimes = []
    check_cmd()
```

Answer (score 3):

I'll just focus on `fetch_page()`.  Using `wget` to download a Wikipedia article to a file, just to delete it immediately afterwards, is complicated and wasteful.  You could just do it all in memory, using the built-in [`urllib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.html) library.

```
def fetch_page(url):
    """
    returns the contents of the html file at 'url'
    """
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as page:
        return page.read().decode('UTF-8')
```

However, if your goal is just to list all English Wikipedia articles, web-scraping is an anti-social way to do it.  Wikimedia content is all Creative Commons licensed, and they make [data dumps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download#English-language_Wikipedia) available.  Analyze that instead, and save bandwidth and time.

Comment: I am downloading and deleting the html files because I wanted to change it later so I can keep them as an offline wikipedia archive. Also I know about the Wikimedia data dumps but I only created this project to learn the basics of web-scraping in a simple environment like wikipedia with just basic html and css files that all follow along the same pattern, but I won't actually be using it. Thanks for the help anyway!